# How to locate an element with reference to a text within the HTML using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have a list of URL's that I need to loop through. All URLs land to the homepage of the site. I need to find somewhere on the homepage a link to another section of the site that contains a 'Find a Doctor' because I need to navigate to the find a doctor section on every site.

I've tried to find the element using XPath contains.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Find a Doctor')]").get_attribute('href')
```

This is what the HTML looks like on one specific URL but the layout can be different on another URL since I am looping through various links.

```
<a href="/search/custom.asp?id=2671" tabindex"-1">
<span> Find a Doctor </span>
</a>
```

The problem is that the string is inside a span so that span does not have an href.

I expect the output to be the href to the find a doctor section to the site but instead returned an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is go to parent like below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Find a Doctor')]/parent::a").get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly mentioned, the text **Find a Doctor** is within the `<span>` tag and does not have the `href` *attribute*. But the *preceding* `<a>` tag contains the `href` *attribute*. So to extract the `href` attribute you can use either of the following solutions:

- *XPath 1*:

  ```
  my_href = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'Find a Doctor')]//preceding::a[1]").get_attribute('href')
  ```
- *XPath 2*:

  ```
  my_href = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Find a Doctor']//preceding::a[1]").get_attribute('href')
  ```